# PHP - read CSV from Google Sheets but sheets redirect to login

Tags: php, google-sheets

I have created several sheets in Google Sheets that I'm retrieving with a CSV output through PHP.
It was all working fine until today while I have not changed anything to my code.

I was using this:

```
if (($handle = fopen($sheet_url, "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 3000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
        {
           // BLA BLA
        }
 }
```

It was working fine. If I try to access my sheet directly through the browser I get a CSV file in return but hitting it through PHP is not working anymore.

I have unpublished the sheet and republished it. I have checked my php.ini and it allows fetching urls.

I then tried to use cURL and I discovered that when download the sheet with PHP, I don't get my sheet in return, I get a login page instead while I have published the sheet for everyone.

I have found a blog explaining the same thing, the blogger solved this by adding a &ndplr=1 to the sheet url but it doesn't help.

I don't understand why Google Sheets suddenly need a login when using PHP.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure `Anyone with the link can view` in your Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparentely, it's a global problem that has started a few days ago, there are many other complaints on Google support sites.

The only way around today is to open/reopen the Google Sheets to anyone (through the sharing button)

Comment: Can you share links to the complaints ?

Comment: sure, this is one of them: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/83645178

Comment: This took down a form that's been working for years... changing the permissions to fully public fixed it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. My web app was reading data from the published Google Sheets csv from two different Gmail accounts. One stopped working last week and the other kept working even though they were published indentically. I eventually saw that one had paid Google Drive storage and the other didn't. So I paid the $2 for a month of storage and it fixed the problem. Thing is, I can't find anywhere that Google said we need to do that. I don't need the storage, and I don't even need to security. It's a small publicly available spreadsheet